# mysql to select records where values are in sequence

Tags: mysql

How can I select records where ID1 values are in sequence (of two or more) where TOWN matches

My table

```
TOWN    ID1
town1   1
town1   2
town1   4 
town2   1
town2   5 
town2   8 
town3   1 
town3   2 
town3   3
```

required result

```
TOWN    ID1
town1   1
town1   2
town3   1 
town3   2 
town3   3
```

sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b409f/26

Comment: Would `town2 1` Not also be listed?

Comment: Also, is there a max `ID1` number?

Comment: town2 does not have any ID1 in sequence. No max for ID1

Comment: Sure it does. It has `1`. That is, the length of contiguous IDs is length 1. Just like the first row of town3.

Comment: What if the ID sequence starts somewhere other than 1. Does 2-3-4 count?

Comment: yes 2-3-4 counts. town2 has IDs (1,5,8) and none of these are in sequence

Comment: @SantoshPillai: Dan's work is a good solution for what you want, as said before - but a lot of us got lost and wasted time because the question was not as specific as it should have been.  Incidentally, I managed to get it working for what I thought the original question was, sequences starting from 1, including a single entry: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b409f/30

Comment: @Orbling Sorry, I should have removed town2 , 1 from my example to be clear. Thanks for looking at this

Comment: @SantoshPillai: That's fine - just for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you question is "give me all rows that have an adjacent `id1` field for the town", then simply:

```
select distinct t1.*
from Table1 t1
join Table1 t2 on t2.town = t1.town and ABS(t1.ID1 - t2.ID1) = 1
order by 1, 2
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b409f/35) for this.

---

To also match on another column, add the condition to the join, eg:

```
select distinct t1.*
from Table1 t1
join Table1 t2
  on t2.town = t1.town
  and t2.state = t1.state
  and ABS(t1.ID1 - t2.ID1) = 1
order by 1, 2
```

Comment: Glad you added the `distinct`. ;-)

Comment: How can I make the query match a second column?

Comment: Joins are orders of magnitude faster than exists-based queries. To also join on another column just add the condition to the join - see edited answer.

Comment: @Bohemian. Thanks for the query to match another column

Answer (score 7):

You can use an `EXISTS` clause to check for the next value in the sequence. This code will only match "sequences" of length >= 2, which seems to be what you want from your example.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 a 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM Table1 b 
                WHERE b.TOWN=a.TOWN 
                  AND b.ID1 IN (a.ID1 - 1, a.ID1 + 1))
 ORDER BY TOWN, ID1
```

Comment: Works well for what he has asked for, though I think he needs to specify sequence of two or more items, as that seems to be what he is after.

Comment: @Orbling I inferred that from his example. The code above will only match sequences of two or more items. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. That Works. I have updated sqlfiddle with your solution

Comment: But this will math multiple sequences for a town, eg town3 1-2-3 and 7-8-9. I hope that's what he wants.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, I would like the query to select if sequence is 7-8-9 (not starting from 1)

Comment: @SantoshPillai Perhaps you misunderstand. If there are *two* sequences for the same town, *both* sequences will be output for that town. It seemed that you might only want the *first* sequence.

Comment: I got it now :) . Yes, I would like to have both sequences